# Using prevState to update state but when props from parent change

Tags: reactjs, spfx

I have a parent class component which sends props to a child class component. The props passed are whether the radio button is one of 3 text strings.
Once the radio button is clicked the Parent sends the selected text string as a prop to the child component. This is then evaluated with this function:

```
public componentWillReceiveProps(){

        if(this.props.stateFromParent === 'New'){
            this.setState({IsEvalTypeDisabled: true }, () => {console.log(this.state.IsEvalTypeDisabled+'this.state.IsEvalDistrue');});
            return 'New';
        } else if(this.props.stateFromParent === 'Re-evaluation') {
            this.setState({IsEvalTypeDisabled: false }, () => {console.log(this.state.IsEvalTypeDisabled+'this.state.IsEvalDisfalse');});
            return 'Re-evaluation';
        } else if(this.props.stateFromParent === 'Appeal') {
            this.setState({IsEvalTypeDisabled: false }, () => {console.log(this.state.IsEvalTypeDisabled+'this.state.IsEvalDisfalse');});
            return 'Appeal';
        }
    }
```

The function above is designed so it changes a boolean IsEvalTypeDisabled between true and false depending on which string is passed by props from the parent.
It is half working, but I think I am suffering from the lack of prevState in the setState because when I click on New, then 'Re-evaluation' or 'Appeal' it changes successfully, but if I click from 'Re-evaluation' to 'Appeal' it doesn't change the boolean. If I then click back on New and then back on Appeal or Re-eval it works (as in it flicks it to the correct boolean value).

Comment: This is using the old lifecycle methods, have you considered using the modern lifecycle? http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

Comment: As far as I can tell, previous state wouldn't help you at all. It should work as is. This is the only place IsEvalTypeDisabled is set?

Comment: It's initialised in the constructor of the Child component as null and the function above is the only place it is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting same bool value from "Appeal" to "Re-evaluation". If clause should go alright, but setState basically get the same value as it already had, so no re-rendering should happen.

Just use nextProps. "this.props" is referring to your current prop, before change.

```
public componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.stateFromParent === 'New'){
        this.setState({IsEvalTypeDisabled: true });
    } else if(nextProps.stateFromParent === 'Re-evaluation') {
        this.setState({IsEvalTypeDisabled: false });
    } else if(nextProps.stateFromParent === 'Appeal') {
        this.setState({IsEvalTypeDisabled: false });
    }
}
```

Anyway, as @ggovan mentioned, this lifecycle event is deprecated.

More on that topic [Link to medium](https://itnext.io/react17-or-how-to-get-rid-of-componentwillreceiveprops-c91f9a6f6f03)

Answering your question about getDerivedStateFromProps:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
   if (nextProps.stateFromParent === "New") {
       return { IsEvalTypeDisabled: true };
   } else if .....
   else return null; // Triggers no change in the state
}
```

Comment: How would I write that using getDerivedStateFromProps

Comment: Or whatever I should use in it's place?

Comment: Hi @Giedrius Vickus - if I no longer needed to use props and I simply needed to update a boolean state, what is preferred to use? ComponentDidUpdate?

Comment: @Tom getDerivedStateFromProps also has prevState. So if you are no longer using  stateFromProps prop, but rather some internal state variable, you can still use getDerivedStateFromProps. componentDidUpdate has negative side effects, because it will be fired after render, so you can get additional re-render if you do some changes to variables which are used to render stuff.